# Atomic and conditional map update

Tags: clojure

I would like to update a simple atom, like: `{:a 1}` and return new value just like `swap!` does, only if given key already exists (and return nil otherwise).

This is the simplest solution I figured out:

```
(defn cond-assoc [store k v]
  (when (get @store k)
    (swap! store assoc k v)))
```

but I don't feel it's really atomic. In the wild lot of things may happen between `(get @store k)` and the `swap!` operations. Is there any better solution than that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right, your solution is not very atomic. To make an atomic swap, make a simple function that transforms the map only when required:

```
(defn assoc-if-exists [m k v]
  (if (m k) (assoc m k v) m))
```

Note that this has nothing to do with an atom or with being atomic. To use it with an atom, simply do

```
(def store (atom {:a 1}))
(swap! store assoc-if-exists :a 4) ;; {:a 4}, value changed
(swap! store assoc-if-exists :b 4) ;; {:a 4}, nothing added
```

Notice that this does not return nil when the key does not exists. If you want that behavior, you could check if the returned value contains the key:

```
(defn atomic-assoc-or-nil [a k v]
  (let [r (swap! a assoc-if-exists k v)]
    (when (get r k) r)))
```